# Search Function Javascript-JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, search

Hello could anyone help me, the below code is used for search button but it just retrieve what I write like if there is a word named "Mercedes" and I write "Mer" on search box it will not retrieve it , can I use "like" operator on Java Script ? or any functions on java script do the same?

```
$(function () {
    $('#search_Input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            if ($("html").hasClass("ar")) {
                window.location = "/ar/البحث/?Query=" + $(this).val()
            }
            else {
                window.location = "/search/?Query=" + $(this).val()
            }
        }
    });
    $('#searchIconInsideInput').click(function (e) {
        if ($("html").hasClass("ar")) {
            window.location = "/ar/البحث/?Query=" + $('#search_Input').val()
        }
        else {
            window.location = "/search/?Query=" + $('#search_Input').val()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it seems that you are passing the keyword to another page so loading the search result will not processed by Jquery anymore but by a server side language. Is that right?

Comment: As above - the page/action/method/etc `/search/` is what is actually doing the search, but you've not included that.  Without knowing what that does, it's impossible to say if it allows wildcard searches.